# Installing Jupyter in PyCharm Professional problem

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Professional to install Jupyter and following the tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html

However, after creating the .ipynb file and trying to run it I run into the following error: "This file does not belong to the project". Also I have "Jupyter file outside of the module" greyed out (see screenshot). Is there anything I am missing? I've created a new .ipynb file inside the project (see screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to add a Module to your project.

Comment: Thanks, what does this mean and how to do it?

Comment: Resolved -- for some reason venv was in excluded folders.

Comment: `venv` should definitely be excluded. You should create your ipynb file directly under the `jupyter-dea` folder and not in the `venv` folder.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that your .ipynb folder is inside the `venv` folder. This `venv` folder should only contain the Python interpreter and third party packages. You should **not** place any files you create under `venv`. Instead, put them directly in the module folder `jupyter-eda`.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the scratches folder was not in the project, so it helped to just add it...

[image]